# How to add dir attribute to <html> based on the incoming request's cookie?

Tags: html, vite

I need to set the direction for the selected language.

If it's RTL, I need to set `<html dir='rtl'>`, otherwise `<html dir='ltr'>`.

The selected language comes in a cookie in the HTTP Request.

How can I do that in Vite?

Answer (score 1):

You can query the document for the `<html>`, and set its `dir` attribute:

```js
const setHtmlLangDir = () => {
  const dir = /* direction of lang from cookie */
  document.querySelector('html').setAttribute('dir', dir);
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-change-html-dir?file=src%2FApp.vue)